# Partial template specialization for more than one typename

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, return-type, template-specialization

In the following code, I want to consider functions (`Op`s) that have `void` return to instead be considered to return `true`. The type `Retval`, and the return value of `Op` are always matching. I'm not able to discriminate using the type traits shown here, and attempts to create a partial template specialization based on `Retval` have failed due the presence of the other template variables, `Op` and `Args`.

How do I specialize only some variables in a template specialization without getting errors? Is there any other way to alter behaviour based on the return type of `Op`?

```
template <typename Retval, typename Op, typename... Args>
Retval single_op_wrapper(
        Retval const failval,
        char const *const opname,
        Op const op,
        Cpfs &cpfs,
        Args... args) {
    try {
        CallContext callctx(cpfs, opname);
        Retval retval;
        if (std::is_same<bool, Retval>::value) {
            (callctx.*op)(args...);
            retval = true;
        } else {
            retval = (callctx.*op)(args...);
        }
        assert(retval != failval);
        callctx.commit(cpfs);
        return retval;
    } catch (CpfsError const &exc) {
        cpfs_errno_set(exc.fserrno);
        LOGF(Info, "Failed with %s", cpfs_errno_str(exc.fserrno));
    }
    return failval;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need an explicit specialization, not partial.

```
template <typename Retval, typename Op, typename... Args>
Retval single_op_wrapper(
        Retval const failval,
        char const *const opname,
        Op const op,
        Cpfs &cpfs,
        Args... args) {
    try {
        CallContext callctx(cpfs, opname);
        Retval retval;
        if (std::is_same<bool, Retval>::value) {
            (callctx.*op)(args...);
            retval = true;
        } else {
            retval = (callctx.*op)(args...);
        }
        assert(retval != failval);
        callctx.commit(cpfs);
        return retval;
    } catch (CpfsError const &exc) {
        cpfs_errno_set(exc.fserrno);
        LOGF(Info, "Failed with %s", cpfs_errno_str(exc.fserrno));
    }
    return failval;
}
template<typename Op, typename... Args> void single_op_wrapper<void, Op, Args>(...) {
    ...
}
```

Edit: Forgot you were writing a function, not a class.

Answer (score 0):

Template functions cannot be partially specialized. There are different things that you can do: you can wrap the function into a class template with a single static method and specialize the class template, or you can use SFINAE to select the best choice of function among different template functions:

```
template <typename O, typename Args...>
void single_op_wrapper( /* all but failval */ ) { // [+]
   // implementation for void
}
template <typename R, typename O, typename Args...>
typename boost::enable_if< boost::is_same<R,bool>, bool >::type // bool if condition is met
single_op_wrapper( /* all args */ ) {
   // implementation for R being a bool
}
template <typename R, typename O, typename Args...>
typename boost::enable_if< boost::is_same<R,char> >::type // by default bool
single_op_wrapper( /* all args */ ) {
   // implementation for void return
} 
template <typename R, typename O, typename Args...>
typename boost::disable_if_c<    boost::is_same<R,char>::value //[*] 
                              || boost::is_same<R,bool>::value
                              , R >::type
single_op_wrapper( /* all args */ ) {
   // implementation when R is neither bool nor void
}
```

On the separate template for void [+]:

In C++ you cannot have a function that takes an argument of type `void`. That means that you cannot use the same arguments for the `void` case as you are using for the rest of them.

On the metaprogramming side:

There are a couple of tricky bits here... the `enable_if` is a metafunction that defines an internal type if the condition is met or nothing otherwise. When the compiler tries to substitute the types in the template, the return type will only be valid (and as such the function be a candidate) if the condition is met. The `disable_if` metafunction has the opposite behavior. The straight variant `enable_if`/ `disable_if` take a metafunction as first argument and optionally a type as second argument. The second version `enable_if_c` / `disable_if_c` take a boolean as first argument.

It is important in [*] to note that the functions must be exclusive. That is, if for a given type more than one of the templates are candidates, as none of them is an specialization of the others, the compiler will stop with an ambiguity error. That is the reason for using the `disable_if` in the last template.

Note: I have used `boost` namespace instead of `std` as I have not played ever with metaprogramming in c++0x, but I believe that you can change the `boost` namespace with `std` in your compiler. Check the docs in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is the trick I use to bypass the lack of partial template specialization for functions in C++. Basically this relies on a grey zone between function overloading and multiple function declarations that do not result in a compiler error thanks to SFINAE rules (all `enable_if_t` boolean conditions are mutually exclusive, hence only one declaration is valid given any specific compilation unit context)

```
template < class T, std::enable_if_t< sizeof(T) == 4, int > = 0 >
T do_transform(T inp) {
  // 4 byte implementation
}


template < class T, std::enable_if_t< sizeof(T) == 8, int > = 0 >
T do_transform(T inp) {
 // 8 byte implementation
}

template <class T, std::enable_if_t< sizeof(T) > 8, int> = 0 >
T do_transform(T inp) {
 // very much wide word types
}
```