# What's wrong with this partial template specialization?

Tags: c++, c++11, template-specialization

```
template<typename Retval, typename Op, typename... Args>
Retval call_retval_wrapper(CallContext &callctx, Op const op, Args &...args);

template<typename Op, typename ...Args>
bool call_retval_wrapper<bool, Op, Args>(
        CallContext &callctx, Op const op, Args &...args) {
    (callctx.*op)(args...);
    return true;
}
```

Calling this later in the code:

```
call_retval_wrapper<bool>(callctx, op, args...)
```

Gives this error:

> src/cpfs/entry.cpp:1908: error:
>   function template partial
>   specialization
>   ‘call_retval_wrapper<bool, Op, Args>’
>   is not allowed

Comment: Basically: read the error message. You cannot perform partial specialization of function templates. I already answered this to you in this other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529817/partial-template-specialization-for-more-than-one-typename)

Answer (score 1):

In C++ you can't do partial template specialization for functions, only for structures and classes. So you should either to do full specialization or use classes with static member functions (of course this is not same as functions)

You may use some tricks using classes:

```
template<typename Retval, typename Op, typename... Args>
struct my_traits {
 static Retval call_retval_wrapper(CallContext &callctx, Op const op, Args &...args);
};

 template<typename Op, typename ...Args>
 struct my_traits<bool,Op,Args...> {
   static bool call_retval_wrapper<bool, Op, Args>(
    CallContext &callctx, Op const op, Args &...args) {
      (callctx.*op)(args...);
     return true;
   }
 };

template<typename Retval, typename Op, typename... Args>
Retval call_retval_wrapper(CallContext &callctx, Op const op, Args &...args)
{
     return my_traits<Retval,Op,Args...>::call_retval_wrapper(calllxtx,op,args...);
}
```

Something like that

Answer (score 0):

You need to unpack in this line too:

```
bool call_retval_wrapper<bool, Op, Args...>(
```

Comment: No change in error message if I add the unpack like you've shown.

Comment: @Matt: What compiler are you using?

Comment: gcc (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) 4.4.3

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this ([ideone](http://www.ideone.com/G21SF)) :

```
template<typename Retval, typename Op, typename... Args>
struct call{
  static Retval retval_wrapper(Op const op, Args &&...args);
};

template<typename Op, typename ...Args>
struct call<bool, Op, Args...>{
  static bool retval_wrapper(Op const op, Args &&...args){
    return true;
  }
};

int main(){
  call<bool, bool, bool>::retval_wrapper(true, true);
}
```

I didn't read the full C++0x spec, but is it possible to partial specialize function now?

Comment: You most likely should actually call the function in question, and not just the constructor.

Comment: Yeah, I did it on ideone, just have forgotten to edit the answer :P